# How to handle or Prevent hardware back button press on react native Modal?

Tags: react-native

Using react native for android app.
Using custom component based on react native modal to present content above an enclosing view.

Already tried to react native Backhandler

```
   componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
    return true;
  }
```

or like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
      return true;
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }
```

here is open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19147)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, that won't work. If you check the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#onrequestclose) you will see that you need to use the **onRequestClose** on the modal. BackHandler *"...events will not be emitted as long as the modal is open"*.

Something like this will work:

```
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          console.log("back");
        }}
      >
```

Comment: Hi Francois thanks for providing answer to this question, hope it help others as i asked 5 months ago, i already found the solution of it another day from day i post it to stackoverflow but i forget to remove question, however solution is same as you given, also i found nice library which have same back press support as you suggested and as well as gesture support,  
 link  :   https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal     hope this help new beginners too. And Thanks to you again.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
<Modal isVisible={ProfileImageEditModal}
        onRequestClose={() => {
           setProfileImageEditModal(false)
          }}
/>
```